# Making JQuery templates reusable

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I want to create a jQuery template(s) that will be used project wide.  I would prefer to put the templates in a separate file or files and compile them on project start up using the [template](http://api.jquery.com/template/) function.

I don't want to have the templates in the markup, in script tags.  Is this possible and how would I do it?

Comment: yes. this is possible :)

Comment: In ASP.NET WebForms you can create templates as UserControls; in MVC as Partial Views.  You could also create simple HTML pages containing your template markup and load them via $.load.  I imagine there are a number of ways to accomplish this.

Comment: That's what I did, I created a partial for the template(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RoccoC5 suggested it, you can define a small plugin which will fetch your remote template and then append its content into a script tag to the head:

```
(function ($) {
    $.loadTmpl = function (url, name) {
        return $.get(url).success(function (content){
            $("head").append($('<script/>', {
                id: name,
                type: 'text/template'
            }).html(content));
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

and use it with:

```
$.loadTmpl('hi.html', 'hi').done(function () {
    $('#hi').tmpl({name: 'Tom'}).appendTo('body');
});
```

or:

```
$.when(
    $.loadTmpl('foo.html', 'foo'),
    $.loadTmpl('bar.html', 'bar'),
    ...
).done(function () {
    // All your templates are now loaded
});
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are just used as strings, so you don't even have to inject scripts. Just pass the string straight to jQuery.template. So tweaking what @abernier suggested, you can do something like following. I make the assumption that you name the files the same name as the template name you want to use and you store them in TMPLPATH.

```
    $.loadTmpl = function (name) {
        return $.get(TMPLPATH + name + ".tmpl").success(function (content){
            $.template(name, content);
        });
    };
```